# Get record count between startdate and endate (VBA) based on user input Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table where I have two columns one is Date Received and the other is Date Finished. 
Based on the user input of dates into the form I need to pull out the number of records. 
I have this query, not sure why I get data type error 13.

```
Dim LTotal As Integer
LTotal = "SELECT Count(*) AS TotalCount FROM tblMatchBook " & _
         "WHERE ((tblMatchBook.DateFinished >= [Forms]![frmRptDates]![txtSDate]) AND ([tblMatchBook].[DateReceived] <= [Forms]![frmRptDates]![txtEDate]))"
MsgBox (LTotal)
```

I have this query, which works in the query window but cannot run it on form.

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT Count(*) AS CompletedSurvey
FROM tblMatchBook
WHERE (((tblMatchBook.DateFinished)>=[Start Date]) And (((tblMatchBook.DateReceived))<=[End Date]));
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.
Nita

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `LTotal` as an integer, then you are initialising it with a string, that's why you are getting a type 13 error.

To solve your issue, you have to understand what you are doing: you need to *execute* a query against the database engine to be able to get a result, then you need to read the returned resultset.

A string itself will just contain a series of characters, it will not do anything for you.

The simplest way for you to achieve what you want is to use the internal [DCount() function](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/dcount-function-HA001228817.aspx):

```
Dim LTotal as Integer

LTotal = Dcount("*", "tblMatchBook", "(DateFinished >= [Forms]![frmRptDates]![txtSDate]) AND ([DateReceived] <= [Forms]![frmRptDates]![txtEDate])")

MsgBox LTotal
```

You actually do not need VBA to use this. You can simply paste the following in the `ControlSource` of a textbox on your form and you will automatically get the number of records whenever the user changes the `txtSDate` or `txtEDate` on the form (and they move the focus away from these controls so Access can pick up that they were changed).

```
=Dcount("*", "tblMatchBook", "(DateFinished >= [Forms]![frmRptDates]![txtSDate]) AND ([DateReceived] <= [Forms]![frmRptDates]![txtEDate])")
```

There are many ways to achieve what you want. This is probably the simplest, although `DCount()` is not very efficient or flexible, if you are starting with Access, then you better stick with the easy stuff first and then move on to VBA when you have exhausted the capabilities offered by the rest of Access and you are aware of the limitations.

Comment: Thanks Renaud. I did enter the information on the control source, it displays "0" and it doesn't calculate all the time. I was able to use the code for the button and it works fine. I tend to use vba because I do little bit of coding the sql Thanks once again.